# Testing values in a range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to test if a range of values are between to columns values in a PostgreSQL request.

Let's say `(2010,2012,2014,2016,2018)` is my range of year values.

I want to check foreach if it's `between extract(year from dtstart) and extract(year from dtend)`.

Do I have to generate a line for each value?

```
select * from mytable where
:year1 between extract(year from dtstart) and extract(year from dtend)
and
:year2 between extract(year from dtstart) and extract(year from dtend)
and
...
```

Or is there a syntax that let do it at once?

```
select * from mytable where
(2010,2012,2014,2016,2018) between extract(year from dtstart) and extract(year from dtend)
```

---

**EDIT** Analyse of solutions:

1. @GordonLinoff solution (16625 lines in 1.039 seconds)

> QUERY PLAN: Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..8085.83 rows=14867 width=293)

2. @a_horse_with_no_name solution (16625 lines in 1.113 seconds)

> QUERY PLAN: Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..5577.04 rows=1 width=293)

There is not a great difference on time spent to retrieve lines so in my case both solutions are enough performant. On the other side I don't know how to read query plan costs.

Comment: I think your first method is the best.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I can do it because my request is generated from server code but I need to transpose it to a pure sql version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because you are using `and`, you and look at the extremes:

```
select *
from mytable
where least(:year1, :year2, . . .) between extract(year from dtstart) and extract(year from dtend) and
      greatest(:year1, :year2, . . .) between extract(year from dtstart) and extract(year from dtend);
```

Comment: A bit dirty but that's an idea.

Comment: In fact your solution has higher complexity but lower time because comparison operator are simpler.

Comment: @sinsedrix: I am suprised that this is faster. The range operators shouldn't be slower than the between operator. How much faster is this? Could you run an `explain (analyze, buffers)` for both queries and upload those plan to http://explain.depesz.com/ ? My solution could be supported by an index on the expression `int4range(extract(year from dtstart), extract(year from dtend), '[]')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postgres' [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) for this:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where int4range(extract(year from dtstart), extract(year from dtend), '[]') 
         @> all (array[2010,2012,2014,2016,2018])
```

Comment: Syntax is very touchy, but if I can't find simpler I will take it.